# how to compare 2 load test results in grafana

Tags: jmeter, influxdb

I have been analyzing load test results in grafana and wanted to compare two different load test results using grafana.Is there any way to do so apart from opening two different load test results of grafana in different tabs of browser?

Comment: A bit offtopic but for results comparing you can try to use this thing (actually it might be needed to develop change/develop for your wishes) https://github.com/innogames/JMeter-Control-Center

Comment: The time frames are totally different in both series - did I get it right?

Comment: @ Yuri G yes the time frames are totally different

Comment: @v0devil Need to see  github.com/innogames/JMeter-Control-Center more concretely.